# Finding largest value for $\frac{\phi(i)}{i}$ for $i \in (2, N)$

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, primes

I need to find largest value for $\frac{\phi(i)}{i}$ for $i \in (2, N)$ where $N$ can be as large as $10^{18}$.

I tried this approach , but is too slow.
Finding the just smallest prime number to $N$, as its $\frac{\phi(i)}{i}$ value is $\frac{i-1}{i}$, which is maximum in the range. (See [Maximum of ϕ(i)i\frac{\phi(i)}i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381053/maximum-of-frac-phiii))

So, I was wondering if there is any other faster way to find the maximum value. More precisely I need the value of i where $\frac{\phi(i)}{i}$ is maximum.

Comment: Duplicate of [Maximum of $\frac{\Phi(i)}{i}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/381053/37490).

Comment: @PetrPudlák well you can say that :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that the maxium value is achieved when $i$ is the largest prime smaller than $N$, your problem is equivalent to finding the largest prime smaller than $N$.

There are many ways to test for primality, so presumably you could just take your favorite primality test and run a for loop from $N-1$ downwards, to find the first number which is prime.

Perhaps I do not understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I tried this approach using Miller-Rabin but it takes 1 minute on my system for 10^18. So, I was looking for any other faster way of finding.

Comment: Use sieving first to dramatically improve your running time.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, seiving algorithm is dramatically slower than Miller-Rabin in this case, because he just need one number, also his test was wrong, I suggest a very fast prime algorithm for him, but he added very bad implementation to the algorithm. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11883/what-is-the-fastest-to-find-just-smallest-prime-number-to-a-given-number-n-where/11884#11884

Comment: Surely it still makes sense to skip over all even numbers? There is a tradeoff here. While the primality testing algorithm is fast, you'll have to test around $\log N$ integers until you actually find a prime.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, anyway I updated my answer there, but for other readers, when you know the bound you can skip the pseudoprime numbers for specific range, and for this range there are just 8 forbidden number to take care of them, so is constant number of iteration after Miller-Rabin.